# iTerm2 intermittently gets stuck on pasting old clipboard contents

Tags: iterm

As described in the title: sometimes iTerm2 does not realize that the clipboard has been updated.

I have verified the problem were specific to iTerm2 by pasting the newer clipboard contents into other applications e.g.

- copy into clipboard from one editor (e.g. intellij)
- paste into a different editor : e.g. vi

But the pasting to *iTerm2* is showing old clipboard contents. The above is repeatable once it starts happening - which is maybe once a day as an idea of frequency.

In the past I have resorted to shutting down the iTerm2 session. Then the clipboard works fine immediately.  But at this moment I am frustrated with that approach because of a remote session that I really do not want to kill for such a trivial reason.

Are there any workarounds found for this?

I am using iTerm2 build 3.2.7 on  High Sierra.

**Update** : I also tried to use the *Advanced Paste* but the contents there are *also* the old/incorrect earlier version of clipboard.

Another update: I have appended to an existing issue on iTerm2. The issue has not been adequately recognized at this point it seems . 
https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/6865